# How to run a codeigniter controller function using exec command in php

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I am using xampp with my local window system.
now a day I am working with codeigniter, I am trying to run a mycontroller function as a background job. Like

```
class Admin extends MX_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        echo "working";
        $command = "D:\xampp\php\php D:\xampp\htdocs\client\newslatter\index.php  admin preget";
        echo $out = exec( $command);
        echo "here";
    }

    function preget(){
        echo "<br/>Done!!!!!!";
    }
}
```

I am not able to run a function using exec command can any one help out my problem?.

Comment: Surely you want to use the URL rather than the path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has a page in it´s manual that is exactly about this:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Note that, in your command, you just put the path to the file, you didn´t add "php"

$command = "php D:\xampp\php\php D:\xampp\htdocs\client\newslatter\index.php  admin preget";

Maybe this solve your problem.

Is php.exe in the "Path" enviroment variable of your windows?

The process should be pretty easy: you run > "cmd" in Windows and navigate to your CodeIgniter project.

$ cd /path/to/project;
$ php index.php YourController ControllerMethod

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using windows.  To do this in Windows, I believe 'exec()' works by just calling like how you do on your command prompt using the "php" command, assuming that you have "php" installed as your environment variable.

So your $command would be

```
$command = "php D:\xampp\php\php D:\xampp\htdocs\client\newslatter\index.php admin preget";
```

However, FYI, this is a synchronous call.

If you want to do an async one (which a lot of times you would want), it doesn't work this way.
I did some research previously as I had this problem.  This is probably what you're looking for when you wanna run exec on Windows with async.

```
$WshShell = new COM('WScript.Shell'); 
$oExec = $WshShell->Run('php D:\xampp\php\php D:\xampp\htdocs\client\newslatter\index.php admin preget', 0, false);
```

Hopefully that helps?

Thomas